# Sound device not detected Debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, drivers, audio, pulseaudio

I'm using Debian Jessie on dell inspiron. It was working fine earlier.  Now, not working at all.

```
 lspci|grep Audio
```

Returns empty.

What could be the problem and how do I fix it? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: If you run into strange issues with a command using `grep`, the first step is to remove `grep` and see what `lspci` shows you:  if the audio device really disappeared, or just the string "Audio" vanished. If the device really disappeared, check your BIOS settings; some BIOS can disable audio device(s).

Comment: Thanks. Audio device was not appearing, not just the string. It's working now.

Comment: So how did you fix it? Write up an answer and accept it, for the next person who as a similar problem.

Comment: I've mentioned what I did in the comment. Frankly I do not know how it started working again or what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your pci database:

```
update-pciids
```

the manpage `man update-pciids`:

> update-pciids  fetches the current version of the pci.ids file from the
>          primary distribution site and installs it.

Comment: Thanks! I did. It returned a message saying that it downloaded dailysnapshot. But   `lspci|grep Audio` still returns empty. Just to inform, in Sound settings, "Choose a device for sound output" only shows "Dummy Output". (It was showing same even before update-pciids, and now also).

Comment: Now it's giving 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21). Not sure what exactly worked, I did this also -  alsactl init